# Sum the values of two columns in the same row in sqlite db

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Consider a sqlite database table like this:

```
ID | Num1(INTEGER) | Num2(INTEGER)
---|---------------|--------------
1  |      10       |      30
---|---------------|--------------
2  |      46       |      70
```

How can I sum values of Num1 and Num2 which are in the same row with each other?
For example how can I sum 46 with 70?

Comment: Hint:  `+`.  That is the addition operator in SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks dude. I didn't know such a operator exists:|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly valid to use an expression in a `SELECT` statement.

For the table above:

```
SELECT Num1 + Num2 FROM myTable;
```

Will return:

```
| Num1 + Num2 |
|-------------|
|          40 |
|         116 |
```